# Bash fastCGI displays a lot of information when no args are given

Tags: bash, nginx, fastcgi

Steps to reproduce create a bash script to run from FastCGI via NGINX, provide no vars in the URL bar.

Nginx Location:

> ```
> location ~ (\.cgi|\.py|\.sh|\.pl|\.lua)$ {
>     gzip off;
>     autoindex on;
>     fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
>     include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
>     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; 
> }
> ```

Top of the Bash script:

> ```
> # Save the old internal field separator.
> OIFS="$IFS"
> # Set the field separator to & and parse the QUERY_STRING at the ampersand.   
> IFS="${IFS}&"   
> set $QUERY_STRING
> Args="$*"  
> IFS="$OIFS"
> ```

Expected output: Nothing

Actual Output:
Note the output has been sanitized

> BASH=/bin/bash 
>       BASHOPTS="" 
>       BASH_ALIASES=""
>       BASH_ARGC=""
>       BASH_ARGV=""
>       BASH_CMDS=""
>       BASH_LINENO=""
>       BASH_SOURCE=""
>       BASH_VERSINFO=""
>       BASH_VERSION=""`
>       CONTENT_LENGTH=""
>       CONTENT_TYPE=""
>       DAEMON_OPTS=""
>       DIRSTACK=""
>       DOCUMENT_ROOT=""
>       DOCUMENT_URI=""
>       EUID=""
>       FCGI_ROLE=""
>       GATEWAY_INTERFACE=""
>       GROUPS=""
>       HOME=""
>       HOSTNAME=""
>       HOSTTYPE=""
>       HTTPS=""
>       HTTP_ACCEPT=""
>       HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING=""
>       HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE=""
>       HTTP_CONNECTION=""
>       HTTP_COOKIE=CID=""
>       HTTP_HOST=""
>       HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS=""
>       HTTP_USER_AGENT=""
>       IFS=""
>       INVOCATION_ID=""
>       JOURNAL_STREAM=""
>       LANG=""
>       LOGNAME=""
>       MACHTYPE=""
>       OIFS=""
>       OPTERR=""
>       OPTIND=""
>       OSTYPE=""
>       PATH=""
>       PIPESTATUS=""
>       PPID=""
>       PS4=""
>       PWD=""
>       QUERY_STRING=""
>       REDIRECT_STATUS=""
>       REMOTE_ADDR=""
>       REMOTE_PORT=""
>       REQUEST_METHOD=""
>       REQUEST_SCHEME=""
>       REQUEST_URI=""
>       SCRIPT_FILENAME=""
>       SCRIPT_NAME=""
>       SERVER_ADDR=""
>       SERVER_NAME=""
>       SERVER_PORT=""
>       SERVER_PROTOCOL=""
>       SERVER_SOFTWARE=""
>       SHELL=""
>       SHELLOPTS=""
>       SHLVL=""
>       TERM=""
>       UID=""
>       USER=""
>       _=""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the intent is with the `set $QUERY_STRING` line, but that's the one that's causing the output. The [set builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) in bash will output the environment if it's called without any valid options.

Comment: Since I was only passing one parameter form cgi, I was able to remove the set and just directly call $query_string inplace of $args[*]